# How to troubleshoot automapper when map one object to another

Tags: automapper

I have this line of code 
var bilagaAttSpara = _mapper.Map(blankettUtskick.Bilaga);

bilagaAttSpara  is alwaws null , How can I check why ?

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html). But I would bet `blankettUtskick.Bilaga` is null :)

Comment: i Can not find BuildExecutionPlan , I am using  automapper v 4.2.1.0

Comment: Then I'm afraid that all you can do is to really understand how AM works. Or upgrade.